# why my app is not available on google play for the device i wrote it on

Tags: android, google-play

I published an app on google play

yet it gives me that for the devices i wrote it on (Asus Nexus 7 and Samsung Galaxy s3)

that it is not available for them

why is that?

what do i need to do to change it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your manifest file, its for Nexus 7 tablet, Nexus 7 has an unusual tvdpi density. So may be that is the problem you are facing. Just try this hope it will help you.

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
```

Comment: what about the samsung galaxy?

Comment: I am not sure about that one but u can check it.

Comment: <supports-screens
        android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="213"
        android:largestWidthLimitDp="300"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />